# What would be an adequate patient involvement in cancer clinical trials?

Tags: research

(1) complains about the low patient and physician involvement in cancer clinical trials:

> Of the 1.4 million patients with a new diagnosis of cancer in 2008
>   (ACS, 2008), **it is estimated that no more than 5 percent of patients enrolled
>   in clinical trials, with some estimates suggesting that less than 3 percent
>   of patients enrolled in clinical trials** (reviewed by ENACCT-CCPH, 2008).
>   Likewise, reimbursement concerns, a lack of awareness of clinical trials, physician
>   or patient preference for standard therapies, excessive regulatory burdens,
>   and time constraints prevent many physicians from enrolling patients
>   in clinical trials (C-Change and Coalition of Cancer Cooperative Groups,
>   2006; Mansour, 1994; Somkin et al., 2005).

What would be an adequate patient involvement in cancer clinical trials? I.e., in an ideal world, what percentage of patients should be enrolled
in clinical trials?

---

- (1) Mendelsohn, John, Harold L. Moses, and Sharyl J. Nass, eds. A National Cancer Clinical Trials System for the 21st Century:: Reinvigorating the NCI Cooperative Group Program. National Academies Press, 2010. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10638934128167382656&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

Comment: This seems to me opinion-based.

Comment: @Susan a statistically grounded answer doesn't seem impossible.

Comment: This seems more of a statistics question, asking about the validity of the sample size. Perhaps migrate to stat.SE?

Comment: @DaveL I think it's a bit more than statistical powers, as it would also depends on other things e.g. the number and coverage of medical treatments that need to be tested.